# Update 3d matrix with coordinates in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm trying to create a 3d matrix in javascript, and then I want to update its values by using its coordinates:

```
var xAxis = [];
var yAxis = [];
var ZAxis = [];
var dimensions = 4;

//initalize matrix

for (var i=0;i<dimensions;i++){
    xAxis.push(0);
}
for (var j=0;j<dimensions;j++){
    yAxis.push(xAxis);
}
for (var k=0;k<dimensions;k++){
    matrix.push(yAxis);
}

//check value of one point in the matrix
matrix[1][2][3]; //returns 0 as expected
//update value of matrix using same coordinates
matrix[1][2][3] = 2;
```

When I run the last step, it will not only update my expected [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO4GP.jpg)[2][3] coordinates, but it also updates every third value of every array to 2 as you will see in the image:
[image]

How can I manage to update only the value that I want?? I mean, the number 2 should only be in one coordinate point, in this case [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO4GP.jpg)[2][3].

**Note:**
I think it's got something to do that it might be assigning the original arrays into the matrix instead of new copies of themselves, so when I update one coordinate, I'm actually updating the original array, and the other arrays are just pointing at the original, so that's why it's been reflected there as well?

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference. Then if you modify one array, you modify the others.

Comment: I have changed `yAxis.push(xAxis);` to `yAxis.push(xAxis.slice(0));` and it seems to change the behaviour, however i think i have to do something with the 0 (zero) i'm assigning at the beginning as well as it keeps updating the other arrays. do you know how can I achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You push arrays by reference.

Consider creating your matrix this way:

```
var matrix = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(function() {
    return new Array(4).fill().map(function(){
        return new Array(4).fill(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: it works wonders! but what if the dimension is to be passed dynamically? i don't quite understand the function, although i've tested it and it does exactly what i want and expect. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating copies if your array but pass references.

You could use a function to create n dim matrices

```
var createMatrix = function(dimensions, level) {
  if (level === undefined) {
    level = dimensions - 1
  }
  var arr = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < dimensions; j++){
      arr[j] = level === 0 ? 0 : createMatrix(dimensions, level-1)
    }
  } 
  return arr 
}

var matrix = createMatrix(3)
```

https://tonicdev.com/lipp/matrix

Comment: Thanks! clever way to create a matrix of n dimensions, I think you've made me realize that i did not use the word dimensions correctly, as it is a 3d Matrix, but the XYZ axis have the same length, but it will always be only XYZ. thank you!